# GtkTreeView returning errors when window is shown, other GtkTreeView shows none

Tags: c, gtk

I'm receiving errors from Gtk that I can't track down. Every time my mouse moves over the GtkTreeView it spams these errors making debugging a hell of a task.

```
(a.out:15168): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_list_store_get_value: assertion `column < list_store->n_columns' failed

(a.out:15168): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_object_set_property: assertion `G_IS_VALUE (value)' failed

(a.out:15168): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_value_unset: assertion `G_IS_VALUE (value)' failed
```

The treeview and it's model were built in glade, and the other one seems to be pretty much the same so tracking this problem down is very hard.

The more handlers I attach to this treeview, the more error messages are spammed when the window is shown.

I'd post the source but it's one big 50k messy file and if the problem is in there then I have no idea where.

I slimmed it down to 20 lines or so just initializing the interface, still had the error. Then I manually looked at the gtkbuilder xml file to try and see any differences. Still had the error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There was a well-hidden option set to a non-existent column in the model. I should have spotted that.

Comment: I had accidentally set a widget to take a value from a column in the model that no longer existed, causing the issue.